# Generating new data in curve (polyline) by interpolation of existing data in this curve

Tags: qgis, interpolation, vector-layer, altitude

I am trying to add altitude data on the vertex of a polyline in QGIS.

I have extracted points from the vector layer of the polyline to update the Z-value.

I have altitude for some points, new points have been added by a refinement of the initial curve.

New points have a `NULL` value for altitude (*"elev_ft"*).

[image]

How can I add altitude for these new points by interpolation on the altitudes already known?

Interpolation should be based on the distance of the path between the points.

Comment: How many points with NULL values exist between points with known values?

Comment: This number is not constant as shown on the examples

Answer (score 1):

It would not seem to be logically possible unless you have a terrain dataset.
height is not a uniform characteristic that can be generated since the values you have are probably need to turn into ranges and don't have a straight progression so then you would need algorithms using intervals. You  could use some type of gap filling on a triangulated network and make a tessellation. Might try working with b-splines in another application that uses georeference such as 3d modelling programs.

Comment: The lines are not representative of the terrain but are 3D trajectories. The assumption is the slope between marked point is constant. The Z value could be computed only for a limited set of points